# Video playback causes Xorg Segmentation fault then Logout

Tags: xorg

When I play a video ubuntu crashes and logs me out.

looking at Xorg.log I see:

```
[    24.129] (EE) Backtrace:
[    24.129] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f82e356c848]
[    24.129] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f82e33c3000+0x1ad539) [0x7f82e3570539]
[    24.129] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f82e24bf000+0x10340) [0x7f82e24cf340]
[    24.129] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f82dcca9000+0x67046) [0x7f82dcd10046]
[    24.129] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f82dcca9000+0xeeff3) [0x7f82dcd97ff3]
[    24.129] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f82dcca9000+0xb42ba) [0x7f82dcd5d2ba]
[    24.129] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7f82e33c3000+0xf383f) [0x7f82e34b683f]
[    24.129] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7f82e33c3000+0x55f0e) [0x7f82e3418f0e]
[    24.129] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/X (0x7f82e33c3000+0x59d9a) [0x7f82e341cd9a]
[    24.129] (EE) 9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f82e0efdec5]
[    24.129] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (0x7f82e33c3000+0x451ee) [0x7f82e34081ee]
[    24.129] (EE) 
[    24.129] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[    24.129] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    24.129] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    24.129] (EE) 
[    24.129] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Worked around it by disabling video acceleration on VLC.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and add e.g. how to exactly change this setting or why you think that this solves it.

Comment: thanks for your reply koeng. 
deselecting "Accelerated video output (Overlay)" option in the simple preferences of vlc allowed me to play video. 
but this doesnt help for other media players e.g parole, dragon. I think that "accelerated video output" should work and has been up until now... 

I will look at rolling back intel_drv and/or xorg. 
I am open to other suggestions...